# Linked list items persistent after deletion

Tags: c++, linked-list, delete-operator

I have written a doubly-linked list (to store prime numbers in this case), the elements of which I am trying to delete after using the list. I have written a simple loop in the list's destructor. However, I am able to print the value held in each element after it has been deleted. I would expect a 'bad access' error after the memory was freed. Furthermore, I have used Activity Monitor to display the resources in use at various points in the programme's execution. There was a large increase in memory use when the linked list was created (obviously), but there was also a minor increase after the destructor was called. I gather that something is wrong.

The 'delete' statement is being called for each member of the list, but it appears not to be doing anything. I have included the relevant code from the destructor below. The list and elements are created using the 'new' statement. The 'current', 'head' and 'tail' tags are pointers to the list elements (nodes).

```
PrimeList::~PrimeList()
{
    // delete list elements
    do
    {
        current = tail;
        tail = tail->previous;
        delete current;
    }
    while( tail != NULL );

    // nullify the pointers
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
    current = NULL;

    // reset size
    size = 0;
}
```

Any insights?

Comment: Are you using managed C++ (meaning .NET / CLR)?

Answer (score 2):

Deleting an object won't necessarily alter the memory that the object used to occupy, let alone make that memory unavailable for subsequent access. There are various ways to ensure that your program does not access deleted memory, such as using a debug allocator that overwrites deleted memory with an unusual bit pattern, or using a dynamic analysis tool such as [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: Indeed, I had considered that. However, from previous experience, when an object was deleted (because it went out of scope, for example) any subsequent attempt at access would generally cause an 'exec_bad_access' error to be thrown. Would one not expect Activity Monitor to reflect the memory that has been liberated? After all, it displays the resources that are occupied by a given process. If not, is there any more rigorous way of determining whether the statements are working?

Comment: Sorry, I had missed your last comment there about Valgrind. I'll try it, thank you.

Comment: The operating system typically only provides whole pages of memory at a time. Because it is inefficient to allocate one small object per page, the CRT generally subdivides the page in some way in order to satisfy the memory allocation. There are various algorithms to do this with different performance characteristics. In particular, when you free your object, the CRT may not release the page to the operating system, even when your object was the last allocation using that page.

Comment: @user1626481: When you say "the memory that has been liberated", you are implicitly using a concept of "memory" that doesn't exist on a modern operating system. Physical memory is *always* liberated because the OS can take it any time it wants -- there's nothing the program needs to do to liberate physical memory. And virtual memory is not a scarce resource, the OS can make tons of it at near-zero cost. There isn't really anything to liberate except back to the process reuse pool of virtual memory space.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: "Physical memory is always liberated because the OS can take it any time it wants -- there's nothing the program needs to do to liberate physical memory." - not really.  Unless you've guaranteed you're not going to access the memory again, the OS must save that memory somewhere, for instance by paging.  So the OS can't take back any physical memory unless you do something unusual (munmap the virtual address, or exit your process, maybe others?).  Absent that, the OS can only convert it from fast to slow physical memory.

Comment: @KeithRandall: By "Physical memory", I mean RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing an element after having deleted it is a bug. Of course code with bugs in it won't work like you expect. That's why we try to avoid such code.

Your destructor looks fine. Most likely, what's happening is that internally your destructor is just making the memory available for re-use. Since you aren't changing its contents or allocating any new objects, it still "happens to have" the same contents.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I recognise that I should not access the memory address after deletion, and it does not surprise me to find the same data in those locations as they had previously. Indeed, why would they unless something else had been assigned to those memory locations. However, my concern is that Activity Monitor seems to reflect that the memory is still in use (a lot of memory when one is storing all of the primes under 1G)! Is there any rigorous way of seeing if the delete statements have done their job?

Comment: @user1626481: The virtual memory is still in use because virtual memory is effectively free (so no reason to free it) and no better use has been found for it by the process. The physical memory is still in use because the OS has not yet found a better use for it. There's no rigorous way to see if the delete statements have done their job other than tools like `valgrind`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you pass the head of the list to the delete method by reference?

Otherwise, you are just trying delete a copy of the list so the list is still there when you try to access it.

I can't see you whole code, but for the destructor, you should do something like this:

```
PrimeList::~PrimeList()
{
  deleteList( &head); // pass the reference to the head pointer
}

void PrimeList::deleteList( struct node** headRef)
{
  struct node* head = *headRef;
  // now apply your deletion algorithm
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your example. No, I did not. I placed my deletion algorithm within the destructor itself... perhaps not the best practice in itself. Should that not work nevertheless?

Comment: Well, yes, actually it should work anyway but it makes it easier to debug if you just have to look at the deletion method itself and its better practice. Try making a few drawings to further investigate the problem, you may also check out the nice guide on http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/ that gives tips for potential problems. The code there is mainly C but not that different from C++.

Answer (score 1):

All `delete` does is make the memory used by the object available for reuse by another object (and call the destructor, if any).  It doesn't erase the memory or mark it as unusable or anything else (at least, it isn't guaranteed to - it may if it feels like it).  At some future time that memory may be allocated to another object, at which time it will be overwritten.

`delete`d memory is not given back to the system, it is retained by your process to be reused by future `new`s (and `malloc`, ...).  This is why Activity Monitor still thinks you're using that memory.  There are better ways of determining whether you have correctly deallocated your list, do a search for "c++ memory leak detector" or some such.

Comment: I think with this comment and others, you have put my mind at ease. Thank you. I will take your advice.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely your compiler who is 'helping you'. A nice way to implement a destructor in linkedlists is by recursion. Assuming you have a class Node for each entry in your list,

```
class Node {
    public:
    ~Node() {delete this->next;}
};

PrimeList::~PrimeList() {
    delete head;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about that solution. In this example, I have used a struct rather than a class.